# Possible to search breakpoints in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a simpler way to find breakpoints in RStudio besides scrolling and visually looking for the red dot, or an alternative to running the script in debug mode? The official keyboard shortcut documentation doesn't seem to have anything like that (see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts )

Comment: Well, without running the script once, how is the program going to know where a breakpoint is? running the script in debug mode might just be the best way

Comment: so this feature is beyond any IDE ?